# Javascript closure access with callbacks inside loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

what  shall I do to make the last row of code return a value?

```
$scope.runActionwithObjects = function() {

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Objects.length; i++) {
                console.log($scope.Objects[i]); //$scope is accessible
                $http.get($scope.Objects[i]["Commit"]).success(function (data) {
                    console.log($scope.Objects[i]);//return undefined
```

Comment: Return a value to where? (Where's the rest of the loop and the outer function?)

Comment: just imagine that this is the end of the loop, there is other piece of code, i don't want to show it

Comment: So show a simplified example that is complete in itself. Are you saying you want the inner `.success()` function to return a value to whatever calls `.runActionwithObjects()`? Please be clearer about what you're trying to do.

Comment: ok, I show you in fiddle, wait)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Bronzer/cghwsx2m/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to **asynchrony** of ajax requests.

When the `success` callback is executed, your loop **has already finished** and the `i` variable is already equal to `$scope.Objects.length`.

Try [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). This function will create different closures for items in the array.

```
$scope.Objects.forEach(function(currentObject){
    console.log(currentObject); //$scope is accessible
    $http.get(currentObject["Commit"]).success(function (data) {
        console.log(currentObject);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your `$scope.Objects[i]` is undefined because the variable `i` is always = `$scope.Objects.lenth + 1`, for example you got 5 elements, the i will be 6, because the at the time of callback, it already got the last value.

One solution is to bind needed object to that method, so we can access it via `this`(we can not reference directly by closure to `ref` variable, because it's still stored the last item), for example:

```
           for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Objects.length; i++) {
               var ref = $scope.Objects[i];
               // console.log($scope.Objects[i]); //$scope is accessible
               var successCallback = (function (data) {
                   console.log(this);//return the ref

               }).bind(ref);
               $http.get('').success(successCallback);
           }
       }
```

Comment: @charlietfl: it should be `$scope.Objects.length` instead